# How to get list from list of list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a list of list of tuples:

```
[[(1,0.99), (2,0.95)], [(2,0.97),(3,0.89),(1, 0.80)]]
```

From the above data how can I get the list of list such as:

```
[[1,2],[2,3,1]]
```

Comment: Firstly can you explain what the desired result is supposed to be, secondly can you show your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a nested *list comprehension*:

```
lst = [[(1,0.99), (2,0.95)], [(2,0.97),(3,0.89),(1, 0.80)]]

r = [[i for i, _ in l] for l in lst]
print(r)
# [[1, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

similar using nested list comprehension with a little variance from @Moses Koledoye answer

```
lst = [[(1,0.99), (2,0.95)], [(2,0.97),(3,0.89),(1, 0.80)]]
result = [[i[0] for i in j] for j in lst]
# result = [[1, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with groupby from the itertools module:

```
import itertools

L = [[(1,0.99), (2,0.95)], [(2,0.97),(3,0.89),(1, 0.80)]]

print [[x[0] for x in k] for k, g in itertools.groupby(L)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a more functional approach. Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to construct a callable object that fetches the initial item from a collection, and apply it to each row of the main list using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [[(1,0.99), (2,0.95)], [(2,0.97),(3,0.89),(1, 0.80)]]

ig0 = itemgetter(0)
print([list(map(ig0, row)) for row in lst])
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
```